# Questions on Covariant differential and Gauss curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

if a non-zero vector field $v$ on surface $S$ has its covariant differential $Dv=0$, then what do we know about the Gauss curvature $K$ of $S$?

I guess we can deduce that $K=0$ according to Gauss-Bonnet formula, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What compact surfaces admit a nowhere-zero vector field in the first place?